# Can we change DTS:ConnectionManager, DTS:ConnectionString in ssis Package.dtsx file manually

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl

The Reason behind this question is ,

I designed a ssis-package  in developer system it will be going integrated with asp.net web application to execute a package ,want to deploy the same package in Client/Production system  which doesn't connect with LAN/WAN with developer system (Copy & paste to client),I used default package location in client ,so i program default location for package in behind code..

So ,Is it possible to Change sql instance name manually into DTS:ConnectionManager & DTS:ConnectionString of the package as per client systems

Its all came on my mind while in phase of deployment of the application with package.dtsx in Client system..and i am not clear about the security issues on packages in Client system and methodology to execute the package with dynamic runtime input of (Source path, Destination path, package location ) in client

```
<DTS:ConnectionManager
      DTS:ConnectionString="Data Source=SYSTEMName\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Test;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;" />
  </DTS:ObjectData>
</DTS:ConnectionManager>
```

If you let me know proper methodology to execute a package integrated with **asp.net web application**(code paths basis & supports on deployment too) ,it would be very much helpful ,i read so many articles like [Loading and Running a Package Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090.aspx)  regarding to this, thats not helpful in **deployment** on client/production system

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change this kind of setting programmatically, as SSIS supports 
[configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141682.aspx).

If you want, your asp.net code could amend the configuration values (whether they're in a database table, config file or SSIS environment) programmatically before running the package.

Comment: Ty @SebTHu for your reply, i am working with project deployment model..in sql server 2012 .. even if i code via package model how to get client side configured Values ..and d src & destig path values

Comment: There's no way to specify configuration values directly.  You could either change the configuration from the client, or write configuration values to a file and use the DTEXEC command-line (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231187.aspx) to specify the config file.

Comment: Hi, Do u mention Configuration is handled once deploy it into client system